# Why would spacecraft docking to the ISS have a different atmospheric pressure?

Tags: spacex, crewed-spaceflight, dragon-v2

In the SpaceX Demo 2 Crew Dragon livestream, they had to equalize pressure between the ISS and the Dragon spacecraft. The voice on the stream said that they were bringing it to levels that match Earth's. What is the pressure in the Dragon if not exactly that of Earth's? And why would that be the case? Is it intentional or something that just happens.

Comment: were they talking about the spacecraft, or the vestibule formed between the Dragon and the ISS?

Comment: What is the _exact_ pressure of Earth's atmosphere? (Hint: Why do we have [barometers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barometer)?)

Comment: Because it's hard to maintain the same pressure of the two precisely without connecting them.

Comment: Something that just happens. Try to buy exactly 1 pound of meat at a deli with a 3 digit display and note the looks it gets you.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The pressures of both the Dragon spacecraft and the ISS match the atmospheric sea level pressure of Earth, about 1 bar. But there are small inevitable tolerances of about some millibar or less. So there is a non zero pressure difference between the spacecraft and the spacestation.

When air temperature in the closed spacecraft changes by only 0.3 K, the pressure would change by 1 mbar.

If we assume a hatch with an area of one square meter and a pressure difference of 1 mbar = 1 hPa = 100 Pa, the resulting force is 100 N. On Earth you would need about 100 N to lift a weight of 10 kg.

To remove those small pressure differences a valve is opened to align pressures on both sides before opening the hatch.

Comment: is this first paragraph factual or a guess?

Comment: @JCRMt 1 atm is the design pressure in ISS.  see, e.g,  WIkipedia. It's hard to imagine a reason not to set Crew Dragon to 1  atm as well.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You could drain some air to make Crew Dragon slightly lighter during launch. But then again the Crew Dragon volume is just 10 m^3, so you'd only make the ship lighter by 10 kg even at full vacuum (and the astronauts need to breathe anyways).

Comment: Side question: Why 1 bar? Couldn’t they use a lower pressure with higher (relative) oxygen content in the ISS and visiting craft? I can see a few benefits like less mass, less outgassing, lower structural stress …

Comment: @Michael something like this was used in Apollo 1: https://blogs.scientificamerican.com/guest-blog/apollo-1-the-fire-that-shocked-nasa/

It's quite dangerous, to have more oxygen rich atmosphere.

Comment: @Michael Higher pressure actually reduces structural stress. Think of a soda can or bottle. When you buy it, it is pressurized and quite strong. You can stand on it without any problems.
After you open the can and release the pressure, it becomes extremely weak.
There is one situation where lower pressure and high oxygen content is used: Spacesuits. You want the spacesuit to be flexible and bendy so that the astronaut can move. And one way to do that is by lowering the pressure.

Comment: @Michael, One of the main purposes for maintaining the ISS is to perform experiments in micro-gravity. If you want to see how micro-gravity affects plants or animals, you need to control the other variables. Air pressure is one of those variables, so keeping the pressure at 1 atm is important for those experiments.

Comment: Why was Apollo 1 kept at such a high pressure? The CSM was designed for EVA, so I'm guessing it didn't rely on air pressure for structural stability.

Comment: Apollo 1 at launch pad could not use a lower pressure. The pressure inside the CM should be a little higher than outside. When the pressure outside was decreasing after launch, pressure inside was decreased too.